# Does Debye shielding occur in non-neutral plasma?

Tags: plasma-physics, debye-length

If you have a non-neutral plasma, lets say positive ions, and immerse a negatively charged point source, would that source's field be screened out at large distances? How about if the source was positively charged, would the field be screened out at large distances in that case? What if the source is *strongly* positively charged, to a voltage potential much higher than the ion temperature. Could *any* shielding occur within the region where the electric potential is significantly higher than the ion teperature? Would the field decay in the normal r$^{-2}$ fashion in this region?